# Salvar imagem do canvas com filtros

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, canvas

Eu add filtros de imagens ao canvas, mas tenho que salvar a imagem no banco de dados e quando o faço a imagem salva sem os filtros, salva a original. O meu banco de dados está fazendo conexão através do Ajax e não sei como linkar os filtros com o BD.

Comment: Mostre o que já tentou fazer por meio de códigos

Comment: Você está tentando usar filtros em um base64/file ou ta só aplicando no front/canvas ?

Comment: Eu apliquei no front/canvas e estou tentando usar em um base64/file.